# How to use (install) Swift csv parser in Swift project

Tags: swift, parsing, csv

I downloaded [the SwiftCSV parser](https://github.com/naoty/swiftcsv).

I want to work with this software.  I don't want install with CocoaPods.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Let me know why down vote .Then only i can improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really suggest using CocoaPods, as it just keeps your file & folder structure cleaner.

If you still want to avoid using CocoaPods with Swift you just need to drag and drop the file into the file navigator in Xcode. By doing so, you automatically add the file to the target and the autocomplete functionality should pick it up when using the methods in other files, classes, functions etc.

In your case, take the `CSV.swift` file and drag and drop it into `Frameworks` Folder in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Is need to add that framework to the project

Comment: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: so you are using it like this `let csv = CSV(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "")!, error: nil)
`

Comment: it seems to me you haven't added it to the right target, select the CSV.swift file in your Frameworks folder, look at the right `Utilities` under `Target Membership` and select the mark that is your project name (**NOT projectNameTests**)

Comment: Want to select (tick) or deselect

Comment: Let me know if any import statement  needed

Comment: No import in swift needed except you are trying to bridge from Obj-C or you want to include packaged frameworks (uikit, coredata etc)